# ¿Como crear un modulo, y pasar una variable en la importación?

Tags: nodejs

En la importación de Soket.IO se realiza lo siguiente

```
const express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    http = require('http').Server(app),
    io = require('socket.io')(http)
```

Si yo cree mi propio modulo como puedo obtener la variable que se envía al usar **required()** ejemplo:

```
const myModule = require('./MyModule')(var)
```

como puedo usar la variable que se envía en los segundo paréntesis en mi modulo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En lugar de agregar propiedades a tu módulo exporta una función

```
// MyModule.js

module.exports = function(var1, var2) {
    // Tu código aquí
}
```

cuando hagas `require` lo que estarás importando será esa función y podrás pasar todos los parámetros que quieras

```
const myModule = require('./MyModule')(var1, var2);
```

Si quieres exportar más cosas aún puedes hacerlo ya que le puedes agregar propiedades a tu función y listo.

```
// MyModule.js

module.exports = function(var1, var2) {
    // Tu código aquí
}

module.exports.metodo = function() {
    // más funcionalidad aquí
}
```

Comment: pero si quiero aun tener mas funciones en ese modulo, te pongo un ejemplo en const myModule = require('./MyModule')('DataBaseName') solo le asigno el nombre pero tengo otras funciones que corresponden a consultas de la base de datos como myModule.Users() y eso me da los usuarios, si lo declaro de la forma que me comentas solo va a ser posible utilizar esa función no? no alguna otra

Comment: @RaulUrielAndradeSoto Mira la edición de mi respuesta

Comment: No funciona esta es mi salida:    DataBase
Example app listening on port 3000!
D:\Documentos\NodeJS\Conection\Organized.js:14
    MyModule.Users( res =>{ console.log('res',res)})
             ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'Users' of undefined

Comment: @RaulUrielAndradeSoto Porque tienes que declararlo todo con `let` como variables de tu módulo para que pueda estar accesible en todas las funciones al mismo tiempo. Lo otro que te puede pasar es que algo asincrónico no esté funcionando bien pero con el código que tienes es imposible saber.